# How wide and deep was the Pau City sinkhole?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, revenge-of-the-sith, obi-wan-kenobi, general-grievous

In *Revenge of the Sith*, both **General Grievous** and Jedi Master **Obi-Wan Kenobi** visited **Pau City**. The site was the stage of the conclusive battle of the Clone Wars. But what were the dimensions of the sinkhole the city was built around?

According to Wookieepedia, the diameter (width) of a [Core Ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Core_ship/Legends), such as *[The Unlimited Projection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unlimited_Projection)*, was **696 meters**. In my rough visual comparison of the sinkhole, the width seems to be about 12 times the diameter of the ship, which would result the total measure of around 8,400 meters.

[image]

But do we have any official confirmation on this? And what about the depth, which is difficult to measure like this?

Comment: someone is a fan of **boldface** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've finally discovered the right answer for the depth issue. I just watched [this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0xhj58gC5I&t=3108), in which Visual Effects Supervisor **John Knoll** says:

> We had a sinkhole that was about six feet diameter and about 12 feet high.

[image]

So, according to the model ratio, the depth is roughly twice the diameter. With the earlier determination of 8,400 meter diameter, it would make the Pau City sinkhole **16,800 meters** deep!

Comment: This is a nice find,  however the depth of the model doesn't necessarily reflect the depth of the city.

Comment: Yes I was just thinking they probably would have forced the perspective to make it seem deeper while not having to build more model.

Comment: There's also another documentary that shows a smaller model of Pau City. To me it looks like the sinkhole width and depth ratio is pretty close to 1:2 here as well. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmfqMg9lbTA&t=4484

Answer (score 6):

The [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook states that the city is **11 layers deep**. There's also a mention in the [Star Wars - Complete Locations](http://www.dk.com/us/9781465452726-star-wars-complete-locations/) book that the docking bays can handle [Trade Federation Core Ships](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Core_ship/Legends) (700m x 900m) and in 
the [Revenge of the Sith Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) that the landing spaces were

> large enough to land a [Victory-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Victory_I-class_Star_Destroyer) [900m x 200m]

---

Assuming the main landing level is around 800 metres high and given that the [private landing pad layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls3ne.jpg) used by Grievous appears to be at least 300 meters high, that means that the *average* layer height is somewhere between 500m-800m.

This places **the *approximate* depth of the main Pau City sinkhole at around 5-8000m**, a figure that seems to tally reasonably well with your calculations regarding the sink-hole's width (e.g. around 8-10k)